# Android SQLite / Response Exception in SQLite database

Tags: android, exception, nullpointerexception, android-sqlite, response

Code in one of four different fragments available from main activity file:

In `MainActivity.java` file:

`onResponse()` function:

```
sqliteDB db = new sqliteDB(getActivity());

if (db.selectRows(tempData.getPrimaryKey()) == 0)
{
    db.insertRow(tempData.getPrimaryKey(), [other attributes]);
}
else
{
    db.updateRow(tempData.getPrimaryKey(), [other attributes]);
}
```

`onFailure()` function:

```
sqliteDB db = new sqliteDB(getActivity());

List<String> tempDataList[] = db.selectRows();

for(int i = 0; i < tempDataList[0].size(); i++)
{
    myClass tempData = new myClass();

    tempData.setPrimaryKey(tempDataList[0].get(i));
    [other attributes]

    recoveryDataList.add(tempData);
}

    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList.addAll(recoveryDataList);
    recoveryListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Code in SQLite Database file:

In `sqliteDB.java` file:

```
public class sqliteDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    public Context con;

    public sqliteDB(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        con = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ...
    }

    [Other insert, update, select and delete functions]

    ...
}
```

(Some true names of database attributes and some true names of all four different fragments available from main activity and functions have been removed).

Now, why does this piece of code throw with the following error?

```
E/Response Exception: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
```

What is the way to fix it up?

Let me know if any more information is needed to answer with this question.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you sure getActivity() is not null?

Comment: getActivity() is used from a fragment of an Android activity. These pieces of code are written by someone else and I am just adding new pieces of code to it only.

Comment: that's not an answer, it doesn't matter who wrote it. Check if it's null or not

Comment: OK, never mind that I tried to use sqliteDB db = new sqliteDB(getActivity()); as a global variable to call it both from the onResponse() and onFailure() functions. As a global variable, getActivity() just always seem to assign with to null value only. Declaring them separately in both the onResponse() and onFailure() functions seem to solve with this issue.

Comment: And then, by the way, if anyone does not know about it up at all, global variables refer to common variables and then local variables refer to domestic variables. OK? Never mind that.